# How to get the value of another cell if the only addition to the referenced cell is "-LA" or "-LED'

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, formula, formulas

So I have a full sheet of item numbers that need to be updated for quantities on a daily basis. There are many items that contain two accessories as different item numbers such as what is shown below:

```
1114            
1114-LA 
15894/3
1114-LED
```

What I need to happen is for the value(quantity) of the two numbers with the `-LA` and `-LED` to equal the original item number's (ex. 1114) quantity. Some items have no other option and some only have one or the other, and some have both.

Any Ideas on how I could do this? The spreadsheet is several thousand numbers long.

here is what it looks like:

```
Item number     Quantity
1114               5
1114-LA            0
1114-LED           0
225896/3           2
225896-LED         0
114895             8
114895-LED         91
114895-LA          0
115938/2           91
115938/2-LED       0
```

Comment: Check out the `InStr`, `Left` and `Right` functions.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking for. Can you give us an example of the output you hope to see?

Comment: Sorry its not too clear. 

basically this is what i want to see
1114            0
1114-LA       0
1114-LED    0

after formula
1114            5
1114-LA       5
1114-LED    5

Comment: Have you tried something like `COUNTIF(A:A,"1114-LA")` to get the quantity of `1114-LA` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would solve my problem. The objective i am trying to reach is whenever there is an item number in the table (ex. 1114) that has -LA or -LED added (ex. 1114-LED) then the 1114-LED number gains the same quantity as the 1114 item number. 

Does that better explain what I need?

Comment: Edits have been made

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after OP's data pattern change

assuming, as per your example, that:

- unknown accessories per item number
- accessories follow immediately after item number
- quantities are in column adjacent item numbers one

you can try this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim iRow As Long

    iRow = 1
    Do While iRow < Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| change '1' to your actual columnn with item numbers index
        If InStr(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, "-") = 0 Then
            Do While InStr(Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Value, "-") > 0
                Cells(iRow + 1, 2).Value = Cells(iRow, 2).Value
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Loop
        Else
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

while an alternative `Autofilter()` + "Formula" approach is the following:

```
Sub main2()
    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| assuming data are in range "A1:Bx" with row 1 headers
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*-*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

where row 1 must be a "header" row

Comment: Unfortunately they are not in column adjacent. Here is what they would look like. 
`Item number Quantity
1114 5
1114-LA 0
1114-LED 0
225896 20
225896-LA 0
225896-LED 0
114895 91
114895-LED 0
114895-LA 0`

Comment: I was actually wrong, They are adjacent, I thought you were talking about something else. I threw this into the end of my macro, but the only thing it does is turn all quantities to "50" until it hits the first item number that has a letter in it.

Comment: I had tested my code placing data you posted as the only ones in columns A and B and with that pattern. Are your data like that? You may want to add some more details about them

Comment: If you look at my edits to the original post, I added the format of what The sheet looks like. 
Here is exact data from the sheet 

`31286/1 24
31286/1-LA #N/A
31338/1LICR 7
31338/1LICR-LA #N/A
31342/1VBL 0
31342/1VBL-LA #N/A
31342/1VPUR 35
31342/1VPUR-LA #N/A`

Comment: So i just tested your code in a separate spread sheet and the problem with your code is that unless each number is followed by both a "-LA" and then a "-LED" number, the whole formula is messed up and no longer functions correctly.

Comment: Your "exact data" doesn't match your question ones in that these latter have item code as a "numeric string" (i.e. a string with digit characters only) while the former have not. My code works as per data given in your question. You should show "meaningful" data along with your question: edit it properly